# Writing to a file and function

Tags: python, file

I have a code similar to:

```
'''
This is main file
'''

path_to_file = './sample.txt'
config_file = open(path_to_file, 'a')
import functions_write as function
a = 1
if a== 1:
    config_file.write("Hello World\n")
    function_text = "Hi World\n"
    function.write_function(function_text, path_to_file)
```

#

Another file for writing functions functions_write.py

```
def write_function(text_write, path_to_file):
    config_file = open(path_to_file, 'a')
    config_file.write(text_write)
    config_file.close()

#################################################################
```

I had expected it would write in order

Hello World 
Hi World

But it is writing as:
Hi World
Hello World

Any thoughts on why it is writing the function first in the file.

Thanks

Comment: because the close happens first, and therefore that part is flushed to the file. The rest is delayed until the file is closed, which happen when your program exists, since you never call it explicitely

Comment: note that this may vary depending on the environment.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't generally have two open write file descriptors to a file as you do. What's happening here is that writes are buffered until something causes them to get flushed. In this case you explicitly call the `close` in `write_function` so it is called (and that write gets flushed) first. The first write isn't flushed until the `close` on its file descriptor is implicitly closed when your program exits.

Comment: I removed close from the function and no close anywhere. Still I have the same issue.

Comment: When the file pointer inside of `write_function` goes out of scope it is calling  `close` implicitly. The larger issue remains, don't keep around multiple writable filehandles. Pass the filehandle into your function or close it first.

Comment: I tried to click the check, but this throws me an error. (An error has occurred- please retry your request) This happens for me in every post. Even for an upvote .:)